# Unable to resolve the ImportError: cannot import name 'spline' from 'scipy.interpolate'

Tags: scipy, interpolation, spline

## Tried to import the following libraries in python.

```
import quantsbin.derivativepricing as qbdp
import scipy.interpolate.interpnd
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from scipy.interpolate import spline
```

## Got the following error:

ImportError: cannot import name 'spline' from 'scipy.interpolate'

Answer (score 2):

This function was deprecated in scipy 0.19.0 and removed in scipy 1.3.0.

So either downgrade your scipy to 1.2.3, or use the recommended replacement `make_interp_spline /BSpline`